# Evaluating the limit of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to solve this problem from a past exam.

> Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Evaluate the limit
>   $$
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\int_0^1f(x)x^{2n}dx.
> $$

Since $nf(x)x^{2n}$ is not uniformly convergent on [0,1] (even on [0,1)), I cannot swap $\lim$ and $\int$. I could use integration by parts, but I would get a horrendous alternating sum that involves repeated antiderivatives.

I would appreciate if you could give a clue to this problem.

EDIT:  While Peter Tamaroff's answer works and is elegant, I am also looking forward for a solution that one can easily come up with.

Comment: $K_{n}(x) = (2n+1)x^{2n}$ is an approximation to the identity on $[0, 1]$ as $n \to \infty$. That is, $K_{n}(x) \to \delta(x-1)$ at least some sense, and checking this is not hard as Peter Tamaroff did.

Comment: The hypothesis that $f(0)=0$ seems irrelephant.

Comment: @sos440 Could you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd rather evaluate $$\left( {2n + 1} \right)\int_0^1 f (x){x^{2n}}dx$$ since $$\int_0^1 {{x^{2n}}dx}  = \frac{1}{{2n + 1}}$$

Note then that $$(2n+1)\int_0^1 {f\left( x \right){x^{2n}}dx}  - f\left( 1 \right) = \left( {2n + 1} \right)\int_0^1  ({f\left( x \right) - f\left( 1 \right)){x^{2n}}dx} $$

and that $(2n+1)x^{2n}$ converges uniformly to zero on $[0,\delta)$ for any $\delta >0$. Use that $f(x)-f(1)$ is continuous and is zero at $x=1$ to make the integral small in a neighborhood $[\delta,1]$. If the above isn't clear enough:

$$\begin{align}\left|\int_0^1(f(x)-f(1))x^{2n}dx\right|&\leqslant\int_0^1|f(x)-f(1)|x^{2n}dx\\&=\int_0^\delta|f(x)-f(1)|x^{2n}dx+\int_\delta^1|f(x)-f(1)|x^{2n}dx\\&\leqslant M\int_0^\delta x^{2n}dx+\varepsilon\int_\delta^1x^{2n}\\&\leqslant M\int_0^\delta x^{2n}dx+\varepsilon\cdot \int_0^1x^{2n}\\&=M \int_0^\delta x^{2n}dx+\frac{\epsilon}{2n+1}\end{align}$$

Upon multiplication by $2n+1$, you get the limit in question must indeed be $f(1)$. Thus your limit is $f(1)/2$.

Comment: grrrrr beat me to it

Comment: @Peter Do you mean in the third equation $(2n+1)\int \dots dx - f(1) = \dots$?

Comment: @peter-tamaroff Could you please explain why $(2n+1)x^{2n}$ is uniformly convergent? I might be mistaken, but if one considers the quantity $\Delta_{n,m}(x):=|(2n+1)x^{2n}−(2m+1)x^{2m}|$ to use "Cauchy's criterion", one has $\Delta_{n,m}(x)=x^m|(2n+1)x^{2(n−m)}−(2m+1)|$ and this do not tend to zero as $n\rightarrow\infty$ where $m$ fixed, no matter how large $m$ is, which means the function sequence does not converge uniformly.

Comment: @Pteromys But in Cauchy's criterion you want both $n,m\to\infty$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff If I recall correctly, Cauchy's criterion is $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists N \forall n,m\ge N\forall x\ |\dots|<\epsilon$; thus to say the function series does not converge uniformly, it suffices to show $\exists \epsilon>0 \forall N\exists n,m\ge N\exists x\ |\dots|<\epsilon$, which I think is what I wrote above.

Comment: @Pteromys No, that is not what you did. Convergence is uniform. The maximum of $(2n+1)x^{2n}$ on $[0,\delta)$ is $(2n+1)\delta^{2n}$. Since $\delta<1$, this goes to $0$.

Comment: Peter Tamaroff: sorry! I need to downvote this answer. The limit in question is $f(1)/2$.

Comment: @Chris'ssis Well, I am saying I am evaluating $$\left( {2n + 1} \right)\int_0^1 f (x){x^{2n}}dx$$ so if this is $f(1)$ then you can see $n\int_0^1 f (x){x^{2n}}dx$ is $f(1)/2$. You should read things more carefully next time.

Comment: @Chris'ssis You don't *need* to downvote anything. Personally, my philosophy (in the past one year, at least) has been never to downvote but just to upvote as many good faith answers as I can. If there's an answer that you think is deficient, then why not post a comment. Downvotes have a purpose, I suppose, when the user is clearly contributing in bad faith but that's clearly not the case here (Peter is an excellent contributor). I think downvoting good faith, knowledgeable and earnest contributors in this way is negative and doesn't contribute to the development of this site.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff How do you know $\int_0^1 f(x)x^{2n}dx$ = 0? Is it okay to split the interval into $[0,\delta]$ and $[\delta, 1]$, to check that the limit of the integration on the former interval is 0 and that the integration on the latter tends to zero as $\delta \rightarrow 1-$, and conclude that the integration as a whole is 0? I am not used to the kind of argument used in analysis and do not know if this counts as a proof.

Comment: @Pteromys I am not letting $\delta\to 1^{-}$. That goes to zero since $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$, and $\int_0^1 x^{2n}dx$ goes to zero.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n \to \infty}n\int_{0}^{1}{\rm f}\left(x\right)x^{2n}\,{\rm d}x
& = &
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left\lbrack%
n\int_{0}^{1}{\rm f}\left(1 - \epsilon\right)\left(1 - \epsilon\right)^{2n}\,{\rm d}\epsilon
\right\rbrack
\\[3mm]
& = &
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left\lbrack n\int_{0}^{1}
{\rm e}^{\ln\left(\vphantom{\LARGE A}{\rm f}\left(1\ -\ \epsilon\right)\right)\
         +\
         2n\ln\left(1\ -\ \epsilon\right)}\,{\rm d}\epsilon\right\rbrack
\\[3mm]
& = &
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left\lbrace n\int_{0}^{1}
{\rm e}^{\ln\left(\vphantom{\LARGE A}{\rm f}\left(1\right)\right)\
-\
\left\lbrack\vphantom{\LARGE A}{\rm f}'\left(1\right)/{\rm f}\left(1\right)\right\rbrack\epsilon\ -\ 2n\epsilon}\,{\rm d}\epsilon\right\rbrace
\\[3mm]
& = &
{\rm f}\left(1\right)\lim_{n \to \infty}\left\lbrack n\ \times\ 
{{\rm e}^{-{\rm f}'\left(1\right)/{\rm f}\left(1\right)\ -\ 2n} - 1
 \over
-{\rm f}'\left(1\right)/{\rm f}\left(1\right) -2n}\right\rbrack
=
{\rm f}\left(1\right)\,{1 \over 2}
=
{1 \over 2}
\end{eqnarray*}